# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object; When using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and EntityFramework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, odp.net

I am having a hard time working with EF and Oracle. Earlier, I have developed an app that use EF and Oracle and have ran well. I installed the ODAC in local computer (GAC) that contains Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.

This time I develop an app that using EF and Oracle too, but I just want to use the NuGet package of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.

this is my app.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="myDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host)(PORT = port))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))"/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=user_id;Password=password;Data Source=myDataSource"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I tried to run a simple query:

```
pulic IEnumerable<int> GetIDs()
{
    var context = new MyDbContext();
    var sql = "SELECT ID FROM SOME_TABLE";
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<Payable>(sql.ToString());
}
```

And it throws exception:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-01918: user 'dbo'
>   does not exist

Then using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250555/oracle-manageddataaccess-entityframework-ora-01918-user-dbo-does-not-exist) I add this to my code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SCHEMA_NAME");
}
```

Well, it run well in my development environment.
And when I try to run it in the server, which didn't have ODAC installed, it throws this exception.

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00955: name is
>   already used by an existing object

Well, it's pretty weird, and I am really confused. Please help.

Comment: That error means that EF is trying to create a table, view,  procedure, trigger or index with a name that already exists in the database. You can do a ODP.NET trace to see what it is creating or just try to eyeball it.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem: You are trying to create tables into the database that it already exists from the previous migration.

The Solution: Delete every thing from the database first and then make your migrations.

There is an oracle query that helps you to make that it's in this link
[How to drop all user tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690404/how-to-drop-all-user-tables)

Answer (score 0):

I have Oracle Database 10g, and when I add a migration through EF Code First, the Visual Studio want to create another Sequence with the same name, delete the previous one, and the problem is solved.