# How to remove all database objects for a schema in java?

Tags: java, oracle, testing, jdbc

Whats the best way for cleaning (removing all objects, tables, views etc.) for an oracle database schema in java?

I can run something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690419/812093 with an Oracle database client but is there a java library or tool which could be used? I know that I could read the connection meta data, iterate over all objects and drop them but I was wondering if somebody did that before and if there is anything out of the box which could be used.

I need this functionality in order for setting up integration tests that
- clean a database schema
- execute a bunch of scripts against that schema to initialize the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Flyway

It looks like the [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org) database migration tool offers the functionality that I was looking for - at least if you feel like hacking :) Since I required the feature just for integration testing anyway it is good enough for me. Let me share my code.

Add Flyway and Oracle driver dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Main class to execute scripts and cleanup db

```
public class ExecuteScriptsAgainstOracle {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception, SQLException {

        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:yyy", "zzz", "zzz");
        flyway.setTable("auto_schema_setup_flyway");

        Database<?> database = DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(flyway.getConfiguration(), false);

// clean the database (remove all objects of the schema)
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.setSkipDefaultResolvers(true);
        flyway.setResolvers(new MyMigrationResolver(database, flyway.getConfiguration()));
        flyway.migrate();
    }

}
```

The MigrationResolver that lists the to be executed files

package org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql;

public class MyMigrationResolver implements MigrationResolver {

```
private Database<?> database;
private Configuration configuration;
private int order = 0;

public MyMigrationResolver(Database<?> database, Configuration configuration) {
    this.database = database;
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

@Override
public Collection<ResolvedMigration> resolveMigrations() {

    Collection<ResolvedMigration> scripts = new LinkedList<ResolvedMigration>();
    scripts.add(script(folder1\\somescript.dml"));
    scripts.add(script("folder2\\someOtherScript.sql"));

    return scripts;
}

private ResolvedMigrationImpl script(String scriptName) {


    String baseFolder = "target\\scripts\\";
    order++;

    ResolvedMigrationImpl migration = new ResolvedMigrationImpl();
    migration.setScript(baseFolder+scriptName);
    migration.setType(MigrationType.SQL);
    migration.setDescription(""+String.format("%03d",order)+" "+scriptName);
    migration.setExecutor(new SqlMigrationExecutor(database,
            new FileSystemResource(migration.getScript(), configuration.getEncoding()),
            new PlaceholderReplacer() {

                @Override
                public String replacePlaceholders(String input) {

                    // just remove parts of the sql that flyway can't deal with
                    input = StringUtils.replace(input, "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;", "");
                    input = StringUtils.replace(input, "SET DEFINE OFF;", "");

                    return input;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getPlaceholderReplacements() {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            , configuration));
    return migration;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Cause your question is not clear, so I'll draw two directions:

Direction 1 - drop all objects and user as well.

The best way is: `drop user <user_name_here> cascade;`
Run SQL statement under user having `DROP USER` System privilege.

Direction 2 - drop all objects but still keeping user (all roles & privileges)

First list all privileges and copy to notepad(for example hr user):

```
-- GETTING ALL SYSTEM PRIVILEGES
SELECT 'GRANT ' || PRIVILEGE || ' TO ' || GRANTEE || 
CASE ADMIN_OPTION 
    WHEN 'YES' THEN ' WITH ADMIN OPTION;'
    ELSE ';'
END
from dba_sys_privs where grantee ='HR';
-- GETTING ALL ROLES
SELECT 'GRANT ' || GRANTED_ROLE || ' TO ' || GRANTEE ||
CASE ADMIN_OPTION 
    WHEN 'YES' THEN ' WITH ADMIN OPTION;'
    ELSE ';'
END
FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
WHERE GRANTEE='HR';
-- GETTING ALL TABLES, EXECUTE, ... PRIVILEGES
SELECT 'GRANT ' || PRIVILEGE || ' ON ' || OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' TO ' || GRANTEE ||
CASE GRANTABLE
    WHEN 'YES' THEN ' WITH GRANT OPTION;'
    ELSE ';'
END
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE GRANTEE='HR';
```

Then drop user cascade;

Recreate user and run the content of notepad file.

Thanks Alex Poole for your suggestion!

Comment: But then you have to recreate the user with all the right privileges etc.. Also the question implies (I think) that the OP is trying to drop the objects of the user they are connected as (but I may be reading too much into "schema in schema"!)..

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a solution that integrates more closely with java. I found a solution that seems to be working well for me. I'll add an answer for it