# How to drop all tables that I have created by sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

`drop all tables;`

or `drop all tables from database;`

Comment: This seems to be discussed in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690404/how-to-drop-all-user-tables

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to generate all the DDL statements using the metadata table

```
select 'DROP TABLE '||table_name||';'
  from user_tables
```

Run the query and copy-paste the output which would contains the statements for dropping tables

Comment: Unless we use `cascade constraints` we need to drop tables in dependency order. A random order will probably result in ORA-02449 exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to `DROP` the user that owns the objects with the `CASCADE` option.

```
DROP USER myuser CASCADE;
```

This will efficiently drop all user objects (tables, views, packages, procedures, ...). You will then need to recreate the user.

---

Else, if you want to limit the scope of your action to just dropping all of your tables (and associated constraints), you could write a procedure that dynamically generates and executes a series of `DROP TABLE` statements :

```
BEGIN
   FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT object_name FROM user_objects WHERE object_type = 'TABLE')
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE "' || cur_rec.object_name || '" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('FAILED: DROP TABLE "' || cur_rec.object_name || '"');
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```