# Unable to drop Table Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, flyway

I am not able to drop a table from my Database.

For the query `select owner from ALL_TABLES where TABLE_NAME ='db_schema_version';` I see the result as OWNER_FC

For the query `show user;` I see the result USER is "OWNER_FC"

But when I try to drop the table using the query `drop table db_schema_version cascade constraints;` then I get the below error:

```
drop table db_schema_version cascade constraints
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Since I am the owner I dont understand why I am not able to drop the table?
I think this table is created by `Flyway` but I am not sure if that is relevant information here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13015653/6700081

Comment: If `where TABLE_NAME ='db_schema_version'` indeed returns something, then you need `drop table "db_schema_version";` - `db_schema_version` is a different name than `"db_schema_version"`

Comment: I tried with double quotes and got the same error. I dont think query syntax is the issue because I was able to delete other tables. only this table is giving problem

Comment: That answer you link to in your first comment only works with upper-case table names. If the table name is lower-case (or starts with a number or is a keyword) then it will fail and you need to use double-quotes around the case-sensitive identifier (as per the accepted answer in that linked question).

Answer (score 1):

> For the query
>
> ```sql
> select owner from ALL_TABLES where TABLE_NAME ='db_schema_version';
> ```
>
> I see the result as `OWNER_FC`

The table name is in lower-case in the data dictionary. This means you need to provide the table name in lower-case in your query, for which you need to surround it in double-quotes, and you may need to specify the schema:

```sql
DROP TABLE "db_schema_version" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

or

```sql
DROP TABLE OWNER_FC."db_schema_version" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```